# Identify refresh or redraw method called in kendo stock chart

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am developing a stock chart using kendo,how it is possible to know if refersh method or redraw method is called.Is there is any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

When the grid is refreshed or redrawn it triggers `dataBound`. This might work for you if you don't mind getting `dataBound` called in other cases as initial load, filtering,...

See an example here : http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/du8Q9/1/